# Overheating of the system in video viewing

Tags: videos

Installed elementary os When watching videos and some apps starts overheating CPU. The HP Probook 4530s . Please tell me what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

the first thing i would do is clean the fan from any dust. get compressed air in a can or via a compressor.  unplug power cable and battery. then spray in the fan holes from the buttom to the exit of the fan heat output.

let me note that windows has a cap of 85°c linux has a cap of 95°c  so linux runs hotter.  therefore a laptop was not build to be placed on you lap use solid underground.

software wise you could install tlp or powertop (only pick one not both)  they will limit speeds of the cpu to maintain better heat output.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and execute `sudo apt install tlp`. That's going to install TLP, a tool that helps with the overheating and powersavings on laptops. You should also update your video drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to make sure it overheats the least possible.